# Problems connecting to my Magento OAuth1

Tags: magento-1.7, server-setup

I am trying to connect my web application to my Magento OAuth1. The problem is when I try the URL //mydomain/store/oauth/initiate I get a page that says: "This webpage is not found" (Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Here is my Apache .htaccess configuration (part of it):

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /store/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

So what am I doing wrong?

More information can be found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

About which URL to use.

Comment: Did you try with `mydomain/store/index.php/oauth/initiate/`